# Different single page applications on same domain but different paths

Tags: reactjs, dns, react-router, single-page-application

I have two single page applications ***video*** and ***messages*** and trying to publish them on same domain ***chat.example.com*** but on different paths. eg ***chat.example.com/video***  to load video spa and ***chat.example.com/messages*** to load messages spa.

I have tried doing this with react router by checking the path then dynamically loading the bundled javaScript

What is the best solution for this?

Currently using [render.com](https://render.com) static site

Comment: `video` and `messages` are 2 separate projects, right?

Comment: yes, two completely separate projects

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 different projects , you just go in your domains host in `www` folder create 2 separate folder and copy each of your apps in each folder, and you can call them in web with your folder names
For example

> www.example.com/folder1
>   Www.example.com/folder2

But if you have 2 page in one app you should use router, check documents from here [react router dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom)

Then in one app, you can access different pages with different URL paths

Hope you get the idea

**update: if your host doesn't have www folder it must have a similar folder that you copy your project files in it**

Comment: I currently don't have the **www** folder cause am using [render.com](https://render.com) web services. They git clone, build and serve from a publish directory in my case **dist**

Comment: Well if you follow my instruction it will works for you, just make 2 separate folder and copy each of your projects in each folder